# XLR cables not a tight fit with SM57s

Tags: sm57, xlr, microphone, cable+

I have a few SM57's that I use at church.  Sometimes the cables "wobble" in the end of the mic and it shorts out. The cables that seem to do this came with a package deal through Behringer. My question is this:  Is there no industry standard in the diameter of the XLR connectors?  OR is it the SM57's that are the problem?

Answer (score 1):

It might be the cables that are the problem, as all of the SM57s that I have ever used have never had this problem.  I recommend exchanging the cables for ones with neutrik connectors.

Answer (score 1):

As the SM57 has a solid body, that cannot differ in its diameter, I think it definitely has to do with the XLR-connector attached to the cable. Just get a better one.

Answer (score 0):

taken from [this](http://www.soundfirst.com/xlr.html) website:

> The IEC Standardized the dimensions of the XLR type connector but specified a very loose tolerance for the distance from the end of the female contact carrier to the body of the connector. Switchcraft brand connectors (and copies of them from Asia) are made to the shorter end of the allowed tolerance range, while Neutrik brand connectors (and copies of them from Asia) are made towards the long end of the allowed tolerance range. At times this results in connectors that will not latch when manufacturers don't properly follow the IEC Standard for their male connectors.

So i second the recomendation made above to switch to Neutrik brand connectors, purely because they tend to be larger.